# Use retuned value of a function on another object on Python

Tags: python

I'm not sure what this is called so I'm unsure what to search for. I have a function which returns a string I need to use the string returned on my instance object.

```
action = getattr(instance, action_method)(request)
instance.action
```

But this always evaluate to `instance.action` where I need it to be the value of action.

I have also tried this:

`instance.getattr(instance, action_method)(request)`

Comment: ok so looking at this then ``getattr(instance, getattr(instance, action_method)(request))`` should work

Comment: You're already using the get-method-by-string-name to get `action`... Why not apply this again?!

Comment: I presume you want to set an attribute of instance and its name must be the value of `action`. Is that right? If that is the case, as @deceze pointed out...